# Google Map & Opera

Tags: javascript, google-maps, opera

I use Google Map API, but Opera browser is job very slow with lag... At Chrome and another browser nice work.

Have we any methods, for optimization or fast Google Map job function.

I have 20 Pin object and 10 Polygon (draw with coordinators)

Comment: Are you searching for alternative library? code review?

Comment: I need Google map, but how i can faster him for Opera and all browser?

Comment: Google Maps has limited support to Opera. Consider using alternative browsers.

Comment: Do you mean Opera Presto (up to 12.x), or Opera Blink (version 15+), which uses the same rendering engine as Chrome? We really need separate tags for these.... @Raptor: Use an alternative browser? Opera _is_ an alternative browser ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As quoted from Google Maps API's Development team:

> Opera is not currently a supported browser for the Maps API.
>   Supporting a browser is not just a policy decision. To support a
>   browser we must add it to our automated test suite, and then ensure it
>   passes all tests now and ongoing. So there is an overhead associated
>   with supporting additional browsers. We have to balance that overhead
>   against the volume of requests we see from that browser and decide if
>   the adoption amongst users merits the cost.
>
> We can not support Opera Mini, because it does not have a sufficient
>   level of JavaScript support. This leaves Opera for Desktop and Opera
>   Mobile. Together these two browsers account for less than 1% of the
>   requests we receive for the Maps API v3. Perhaps the strongest
>   argument for supporting Opera is that it would open up the API to a
>   number of new platforms (eg. Symbian, WinMo). However when we exclude
>   requests from platforms for which we already have a supported browser,
>   that number drops to 0.05%. So right now supporting Opera is simply
>   not a good investment of our engineering time compared to working on
>   features that will benefit 100% of the developer and user base.
>
> Consequently I am going to collapse all bugs relating to Opera into
>   this one, and reclassify this as a Feature Request to support Opera.
>   We will continue to keep an eye on this issue and on the adoption
>   numbers, and if a new strong argument arises, or adoption increases,
>   we will revisit it.

As said in comment, Google Maps has limited support to Opera. Consider using alternative browsers.

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1856

Comment: That quote is currently about four and a half years old. In the meantime, the rendering engine has changed and there's not much difference between Google's own browser, Chrome, and Opera (apart from the latter having some more features).